# Web Application on a Thin Client Based Network

Tags: web-applications, jsf, rdp, thin-client

I am currently developing a web application with rich interfaces using JSF. My application is deployed on Tomcat on a server in the network and majority of users access the server with Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) on that server then they use browser in there. Thin  clients have 128MB of RAM and 16MB of it is reserved for graphics and it has a cpu of 800Mhz. My problem is interfaces working pretty slow on these clients and i am trying to figure out that if that slowness is based on incapability of thin clients.

Answer (score 0):

Do the thin clients perform at 100% load? Can you check that?

Otherwise, have you enabled RDP compression? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885187
Can help quite a lot if the network is slow.

Also, does the server have enough RAM memory to run all those remote sessions? Every user opening a browser on the server might have some serious impact.